# Designing a Queue in C. Segfault when adding element to queue

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, queue

I am having a problem with a queue program I am writing in C. This is a circular queue, so the last item must also point to the first item. The problem exists within the addQueue function. First I check whether the head pointer is set to NULL, if it is then I add the first item to the queue. However, head is not equal to NULL, then I add the item to the end of the queue. I create an iterate pointer to iterate until it finds the end when: 
    iterate->next == *head; 
The problem I am having is that when I create iterate and set it to *head, it is not operating as it should. Here is my code and the output I have received, I added some prints in the code to show the problem I am having.

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdio.h>


 //define the Q element struct
 typedef struct _item{
        struct _item* next;
         struct _item* prev;
         int data;
} item;

 item * newItem(){

         item * node = malloc(sizeof(item));
         return node;
 }

 void initQueue(item ** head){
         *head = NULL; //Empty queue means head points to NULL
 }

 void addQueue(item ** head, item item_p){
         //create new item
         item * newIt = newItem();
         newIt = &item_p;
         printf("NewItem: %d\n\n", newIt->data);

         //if *head is NULL, make it point to item
         if(*head == NULL)
         {       
                 *head = newIt; //set head to address of item
                 newIt->next = *head;
                 printf("Again: %p\n\n",  *head);
         }
         //else the list is not empty, add item to end of list
         else    
         {       
                 item * iterate = NULL; 
                 iterate = *head;
                 printf("it: %p head: %p\n\n", iterate, *head);
                 /*while (iterate->next != *head)
                 {
                         iterate = iterate->next;
                 }
                 iterate->next = newIt;
                 newIt->next = *head;*/
         }
 }
```

Here is the .c file I wrote to test the functions:

```
#include "q.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
 {

 item  i1;
 i1.data = 1;

 item  i2;
 i2.data = 2;

 item  i3;
 i3.data = 3;

 item * headTemp;
 initQueue(&headTemp);

 addQueue(&headTemp, i1);
 printf("HEAD: %d\n", headTemp->data);
 addQueue(&headTemp, i2);
 printf("HEAD: %d\n", headTemp->data);

 addQueue(&headTemp, i3);


 return 0;
 }
```

And the output is:

```
NewItem: 1

Again: 0x7fff2252eb10

HEAD: 1
NewItem: 2

it: 0x7fff2252eb10 head: 0x7fff2252eb10

HEAD: 2
NewItem: 3

it: 0x7fff2252eb10 head: 0x7fff2252eb10

Segmentation fault
```

I created three items to insert into the queue. The first is placed in without issue. However I have problems when I insert a second item. The headTemp->data should remain the same no matter what I place into the queue, however it goes from 1 to 2 to 3, which is the data for all items I created. I'm not really sure what the problem is, and the answer may be staring me in the face. But I would really appreciate some help with this.

Cheers!

Comment: Don't pass a struct as parameter. Use pointers.

Comment: Please, ***Please*** don't number your lines. it makes utterly worthless to cut-paste code for testing. If you have to call out attention to a line for a specific error, add a comment that says "THIS IS LINE ###". That said, its a sad testimony to academia when I'm seriously tempted to up-vote a question solely on the basis that the poster has less than 1K rep **and** is correctly *not* casting `malloc()` (good job, btw).

Comment: Look in your code and see if you can find where your new nodes have there `next` and `prev` pointers initialized to NULL if not set to previously *valid* addresses. Also you immediately leak memory in your `addQueue` method in the first two lines. This isn't java. your code pushes an automatic variable on into your queue, and it will be invalid as soon as your function returns.

Comment: You didn't add the element at the end of the list.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks for the tip on line numbers. This is my first post on stackoverflow, so I'm still trying to get used to it.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a deque or just a queue? For the latter, you don't need a node-prev pointer. And you can make insertion an O(1) operation if you abstract your queue to a structure that holds a head and tail pointer as separate entities. then your queue management simply becomes maintaining that structure. it make more sense in-code once you see it.

Comment: I just tested this (Emacs comes to rescue ;-) and it doesn't crash. I removed the call to `printQueue()` though. because it isn't defined.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, there is supposed to be a dequeue as well. I just ran into this problem before I implemented that. Okay, yeah, I'll go ahead and implement it that way instead - much better approach.

Comment: @OlafDietsche thanks for pointing that out. I cut that out because just to reduce code but forgot to delete the function call to it.

Comment: @CameronKeith your problem might be in `printQueue` where it is? can you post it?

Comment: @JKB I forgot to delete that from my code before posting. But the error was actually occuring before it ever reached that anyways. Edited main post and removed the call to printQueue().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for posting paste-able code.  Right out of the gate, this is wrong:

```
 item * newIt = newItem();
 newIt = &item_p;
```

this is an immediate memory leak. Worse the address your replacing it with is a by-value automatic variable. Therefore the address is going to be invalid to even *evaluate*, much less dereference, as soon as this function is finished.

Next, you need to prime your nodes with valid state for *all* member variables. How you do this is up to you, but the simplest way is in the node-creation code. To really do this properly, your node creation code should be a "factory" function. I.e. it should take as parameters what is needed to initialize the node. So do this first:

```
item* newItem( int data )
{
    item * node = malloc(sizeof(item));
    if (item == NULL)
    {
        perror("failed to allocate node.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    node->data = data;
    node->next = node->prev = NULL;
    return node;
}
```

Once you have that solid, you can modify your `addQueue` to do this:

```
void addQueue(item** head, int data)
{
    item *prev = NULL;
    while (*head)
    {
        prev = *head;
        head = &prev->next;
    }

    *head = newItem(data);
    (*head)->prev = prev;
}
```

This code is still a ways off from being a deque. You need two pointers to do that, and the best place to keep them is in a separate struct, along with a count to make size-inquiries O(1). Properly done, insertion is O(1) in a full deque, but you'll get there eventually.

Anyway, an updated main appears below for testing everything made it in. Eventually you want a pop-functoin, etc.

```
int main()
{
    item *q = NULL;

    for (int i=1; i<=20; ++i)
        addQueue(&q, i);

    item *p = q;
    while (p)
    {
        printf("%d ", p->data);
        p = p->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `addQueue()` function is not appropriate.

```
void addQueue(item ** head, item item_p){
28         //create new item
29         item * newIt = newItem();
30         newIt = &item_p;
31         printf("NewItem: %d\n\n", newIt->data);
32         
33         //if *head is NULL, make it point to item
34         if(*head == NULL)
35         {       
36                 *head = newIt; //set head to address of item
37                 newIt->next = *head;
38                 printf("Again: %p\n\n",  *head);
39         }
```

In this you do `newItem()` to get newly allocated node, but you again re-assign it to `&itemp_p` on line 30. This is not good, as you are not using allocated memory, but items variables `i1, i2, i3` declared in `main()`.

Also, in `newItem()` set `next` and `prev` to `NULL`

```
17 item * newItem(){
18 
19         item * node = malloc(sizeof(item));
           if(node) { //You can use calloc too.
              node->next = NULL;
              node->prev = NULL;
           }
20         return node;
21 }
```